# I need some help understand this line of T-SQL code

Tags: t-sql

I read this line of code in a book but could not fully comprehend its application. I understand this is regarding implicit conversion but don't fully understand the purpose of some of the code.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(

SELECT ISNULL(''5'', 5),

ISNULL(5, ''5''),

COALESCE(''5'', 5),

COALESCE(5, ''5'') ;

' ;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql ;

SELECT column_ordinal,

is_nullable,

system_type_name

FROM master.sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@sql, NULL, 0) a ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll go out on a limb and guess that it was intended to be executable code that demonstrates the difference between two similar TSQL functions. This example should produce the expected results:

```
SELECT column_ordinal, is_nullable, system_type_name FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set  
  ( N'SELECT ISNULL(''5'', 5), ISNULL(5, ''5''), COALESCE(''5'', 5), COALESCE(5, ''5'');', null, 0);
```

A SQL Fiddle example is available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/46228/0).

A careful reading of the documentation for [`IsNull()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`Coalesce()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), paying particular attention to the *Return Types* of each, will explain the results. [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is also illustrative.